# AngularJS - directive with ng-transclude, no two-way binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

See that [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/DbpNk5kEvFZRg81Kih0t?p=preview)

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    {{ obj }}

    <dir>
      <input type="text" ng-model="obj" />
    </dir>

  </body>
```

Why when I change the `obj` scope variable in the custom directive with `ng-transclude` I don't change it in the `MainCtrl` `$scope.obj`.

But when I have `$scope.obj = { name : 'test' };` in `MainCtrl` the two-way binding is working the way I expect.

See the working [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/PeKngyGOb7jfWko2csXG?p=preview)

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    {{ obj.name }}

    <dir>
      <input type="text" ng-model="obj.name" />
    </dir>

  </body>
```

What is the explanation of this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with accessing primitive variables on the parent scope from the child scope. You have a child scope because having `transclude: true` creates a new scope.

You really should read [this article](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) to have a deep understanding of what's going on.

The highlights from the article:

> Scope inheritance is normally straightforward, and you often don't
>   even need to know it is happening... until you try 2-way data binding
>   (i.e., form elements, ng-model) to a primitive (e.g., number, string,
>   boolean) defined on the parent scope from inside the child scope.

And

> This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the
>   "best practice" of always have a '.' in your ng-models.

What happens is that the parent scope is not consulted when it comes to primitives. It's a Javascript thing, not even Angular's.

I've also created a [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/kPO20JXsop9GzVW8c53j?p=preview) of object hiding from child scope. (shadowing a non-primitive object):

```
app.directive('dir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',

        scope: true,
        template: "<div><input type=\"text\" ng-model=\"obj.name\" /></div>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.obj = {name : "newname"}; 
        }

    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that useful information and the link.

Answer (score 0):

The transcluded html generate a child scope of the `MainCtrl` when write this new property (`obj`) the child scope generate a new one that overwrite the parent.

> The prototype chain is not consulted, and a new aString property is added to the childScope. This new property hides/shadows the parentScope property with the same name.

The modified version works because the child scope (transcluded) access first to obj (reference) and then to the property name

Learn more about the scope inheritance at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

And the transclusion and scope behavior at http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/03/transclusion-and-scopes/

Answer (score 0):

This works when you consult the value of `obj` from the same scope - the directive's scope:

```html
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  {{ obj }}

  <dir>
    <p>
      The following text will be synched with the model:
    </p>
    <span>{{ obj }}</span>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model='obj' />
  </dir>

</body>
```