# Angular two-way binding not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is my  drective. `value` is bound to a scope variable (session_number) and change is a function that get the current session_number and perform some checks.

```
return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: { value: '=value',change:'&change' },
                template: '<a href="javascript:;" class="counter-minus" ng-click="minus()">-</a>\
                          <input type="text" class="counter-field" ng-model="value" ng-change="changed()" ng-readonly="readonly">\
                          <a  href="javascript:;" class="counter-plus" ng-click="plus()">+</a>',

        link: function( scope , element , attributes ) {
                        // Make sure the value attribute is not missing.
                        if ( angular.isUndefined(scope.value) ) {
                            throw "Missing the value attribute on the counter directive.";
                        }

                        var min = angular.isUndefined(attributes.min) ? null : parseInt(attributes.min);
                        var max = angular.isUndefined(attributes.max) ? null : parseInt(attributes.max);
                        var step = angular.isUndefined(attributes.step) ? 1 : parseInt(attributes.step);

                        element.addClass('counter-container');

                        // If the 'editable' attribute is set, we will make the field editable.
                        scope.readonly = angular.isUndefined(attributes.editable) ? true : false;

                        /**
                         * Sets the value as an integer.
                         */
                        var setValue = function( val ) {

                            scope.value = parseInt( val );                    
                            scope.change();


                        }
                        setValue(scope.value + 1);
          }

     }
```

I was wondering, why `scope.change()`  is executed before `scope.value`. Because inside `change()` I used `session_number` that is bound to `scope.value`, but always `session_number` has a old value.  Its like when `scope.change()` is executed, `scope.value` did not change session_number variable yet.

Comment: Where is `val` from `setValue(val)` defined ?

Comment: Won't `value` be undefined ? Do you mean you want `scope.value` ?

Comment: @OmriAharon done,i forgot add scope.

Comment: Ok :) Your problem is that you override `scope.value` with the same value, only after you perform `parseInt`. But if it's a number, it's the same value.

Comment: umm not, that is not the problem, I just assigning it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70923/discussion-between-omri-aharon-and-levi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what the problem is, thanks to this answer:

[AngularJS - directive with ng-transclude, no two-way binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503688/angularjs-directive-with-ng-transclude-no-two-way-binding/28503895#28503895)

Two-2-way bidining using primitive values does not work as expected.

> Scope inheritance is normally straightforward, and you often don't
>   even need to know it is happening... until you try 2-way data binding
>   (i.e., form elements, ng-model) to a primitive (e.g., number, string,
>   boolean) defined on the parent scope from inside the child scope.

So I needed to change `value` binding from primitive value to an object.